# SAP / DDLS Usages not deleted after removing custom field

Tags: sap-fiori, cds, sap-data-dictionary

In an SAP System I deleted a field object created over the app "Custom fields and logic". Even though I am quite sure I deleted the usages of the field there are still objects which are in table `TADIR` and also the import as "transport of copies) into the quality system stands still because of ATC checks (067 - CDS syntax check).

Has anyone had to deal with usages that were not correctly deleted and how did you handle them?

We did not try anything except what SAP Standard offers as we are unsure what effects manual corrections could have on the system.
Thanks for your thoughts
Jack